# How to sort an array on time in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, time

I'd like to sort an array based on time so that it goes from the earliest to the latest. What's the best way I can do this?

The array looks like this

```
array([0] => 10:30)
array([0] => 13:00)
array([0] => 11:20)
array([0] => 10:30)
array([0] => 10:30)
array([0] => 08:30)
array([0] => 12:10)
array([0] => 11:20)
array([0] => 09:20)
array([0] => 13:00)
array([0] => 08:30)
array([0] => 08:30)
array([0] => 13:00)
array([0] => 15:40)
array([0] => 13:00)
array([0] => 15:40)
array([0] => 13:50)
array([0] => 13:50)
```

I tried using usort and that didn't work.

I hope you can help me with this problem.

Comment: Look like you have inner array for each element - try use `array_column` first. And please post you code and what have you tried - it will help us help you

Comment: Is it deliberate that it's a 2-dimensional array where each index in the outer array only ever has one time? Will it be possible for there to be multiple times in each? If so, what does that mean and will it need to be sorted?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that,

```
usort($arr, function($a,$b){
    return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b); // if not worked. return strtotime($a[0]) - strtotime($b[0]);
});
```

converting it to timestamp will solve your problem.